# domain name appearing twice in error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've created a WPF window like this:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReVVed" x:Class="ReVVed.Merge_Text_Window"
    MinWidth="400" MinHeight="400" Width="600" Height="400" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" Title="Merge Text" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

I compiled the code and tried it but when I went back and added a Window_Loaded event handler, I started getting this error:

> The type name 'Merge_Text_Window' does not exist in the type 'ReVVed.ReVVed'

I don't know what is looking into ReVVed.ReVVed. The error references line 4 column 22 which is the Minwidth declaration. There is no ReVVed.ReVVed namespace anywhere in my code. I can't compile.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it works but I put the window and code behind into a separate namespace instead of under the projects namespace and it compiles fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this as the message implies the namespace before the class is duplicating the local namespace already specified?

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReVVed" x:Class="Merge_Text_Window"
    MinWidth="400" MinHeight="400" Width="600" Height="400" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" Title="Merge Text" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

Comment: Yes, all the functions and variables in the code behind "do not exist in the current context" if I leave out the namespace in the class declaration.